# Why does my WiFi suddenly slow down a lot, then after I restart my PC, it's fine?

Tags: internet, lan

So, I have no idea why this happens sometimes, but I leave my computer on for quite a while as I run a server on it. Then suddenly, WiFi gets really bad. But after I restart my computer, the Internet is back. Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the network adapter in Windows device manager and then enable again instead of a reboot? Also the question should contain information if other devices like smartphone have a poor connection at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen AntiVirus software cause this behavior.

You could try disabling AntiVirus (but be sure to reenable it).  Backup software may also compound the problem.